# XML - find node, print its ancestors with one text node

Tags: xml, xml-parsing

Question may sound unclear, so I will use example.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?>
<root>
  <item>
    <item>
      <item>
        <item>
          <key>test1</key>
          <Name>Daugther E</Name>
        </item>
        <Name>Son C</Name>
      </item>
      <Name>Child B</Name>
    </item>
    <Name>Item A</Name>
  </item>
</root>
```

I can easily find daugtherE with XPath. I would like some flexible way to print whole hierarchy like

> [Item A] ->[Child B] ->[Son C] ->[Daughter E]

Is it possible? This would save me a lot of tedious manual search and verification. I currently use xmlstarlet on Windows to query and edit XML. I could create python script to parse XML DOM tree and print results, but perhaps there's more powerful or easier way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem with XSLT:
[Is it possible to navigate to the parent node of a matched node during XSLT processing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563644/is-it-possible-to-navigate-to-the-parent-node-of-a-matched-node-during-xslt-proc) - this post was huge help

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="//Name[text()='Daugther E']/">
    <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::item) &gt; 1">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::item[1]/ancestor::item[1]" mode="backout"/><xsl:text> -></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="."/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="item" mode="backout">
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count(ancestor::item) &gt; 0"><xsl:text> - </xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ancestor::item[1]" mode="backout"/>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
    <xsl:if test="count(ancestor::item) &gt; 0">
      <xsl:text> -></xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:text>[</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="Name/."/><xsl:text>]</xsl:text>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```